# Module I'm developing will not install

Tags: add-on-development, module

I am new to EE development and am trying to get my head round creating a module. I've read various tutorials and docs and have a skeleton module created, but it will not install.

In the list of modules I can see the name and description of my module, but when I click "Install" nothing happens. The status is still "Not Installed".

I have checked the database and the modules table has an entry for my module, so the `install()` function is executing, but the status isn't changing.

Here is my upd file:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Photo_pdf_upd {

    public $version = '1.0';

    private $EE;

    /**
     * Class Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->EE =& get_instance();
    }

    // -------------------------------------

    /**
     * Installation Method
     *
     * Required by ExpressionEngine
     *
     * @return boolean  TRUE
     */
    public function install() {
        // Drop info on the module into the modules table
        $mod_data = array(
            'module_name'           => 'Photo PDF',
            'module_version'        => $this->version,
            'has_cp_backend'        => 'n',
            'has_publish_fields'    => 'n'
        );

        $this->EE->db->insert('modules', $mod_data);

        return TRUE;
    }

    // --------------------------------------

    /**
     * Module Uninstaller
     *
     * Required by ExpressionEngine
     *
     * @return boolean  TRUE
     */
    public function uninstall() {
        $mod = $this->EE->db->select('module_id')->get_where('modules', array('module_name'=>'Photo PDF'))->row('module_id');

        $this->EE->db->where('module_id', $mod)->delete('module_member_groups');

        $this->EE->db->where('module_name', 'Photo PDF')->delete('modules');

        return TRUE;
    }

    // ---------------------------------------

    /**
     * Module Updater
     *
     * Required by ExpressionEngine
     *
     * @return boolean  TRUE
     */
    public function update($current = '') {
        // Nothing to do here
        return TRUE;
    }
}

/* End of File: upd.photo_pdf.php */
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$mod_data['module_name'] should be class name of your actual module file (mod.photo_pdf.php), in your case 'Photo_pdf'